# Updating notification using KNotify

Tags: python, notifications, kde-plasma

I've converted a gnome python script to use KDE notifications every time Spotify changes track. The code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Title: Spotify Notification Demo
Author: Stuart Colville, http://muffinresearch.co.uk
Modified to work with KDE: Steve Nixon
License: BSD

"""

import dbus
import gobject
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

class SpotifyNotifier(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """initialise."""
        bus_loop = DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
        bus = dbus.SessionBus(mainloop=bus_loop)
        loop = gobject.MainLoop()
        self.spotify = bus.get_object("org.mpris.spotify", "/")
        self.spotify.connect_to_signal("TrackChange", self.track_changed)
        self.notify_id = None
        loop.run()

    def track_changed(self, metadata):
        """Handle track changes."""
        if metadata:

                title = unicode(metadata.get("title").encode("latin-1"), "utf-8")
                album = unicode(metadata.get("album").encode("latin-1"), "utf-8")
                artist = unicode(metadata.get("artist").encode("latin-1"), "utf-8")

                knotify = dbus.SessionBus().get_object("org.kde.knotify", "/Notify")

                knotify.event("warning", "kde", [], title, u"by %s from %s" % (artist, album), [], [], 0, 0, dbus_interface="org.kde.KNotify")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SpotifyNotifier()
```

This works fine for each notification, but leaves the entry in the KNotify area indefinitely.

Can I either

a) update the event using an ID and knotify.update? I assume so, but I don't know how to check for the initial existence of the event to use knotify.event the first time and knotify.update for each subsequent.

b) Close the event after 30 seconds (or so)

c) Close the event at the end of the song (better than option b), but comes with the same problem of tracking IDs which I haven't worked out how to do)

Cheers for any help,

Oh, also, if anyone knows how to stop it making a little "piano" noise when it notifies that'd be great too!

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event method returns int. That's notification's Id. So, You can use it for closing, updating existing Notify:

```
id = knotify.event("warning", ....)

time.sleep(30) 

knotify.closeNotification(id)
```

If You have to check if it already exist, You can write Id to tmp file, and so on

Answer (score 3):

Easier would be to simply set a timeout upon creation of the notification event:

```
knotify.event(event, fromApp, contexts, title, text, pixmap, actions, timeout, winId)
```

timeout is an integer value representing milli-seconds.